# How does DataAdapter.Update() work with Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, mysql, dataadapter

I'm working with some legacy code trying to understand how it works.

The code has a `MySqlCommand` that calls a stored procedure to populate a `DataTable` as shown here:

```
    _apptCmd = new MySqlCommand("CALL get_appointments(@date)", _systemState.Connection);
    _apptCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", endDateDte.DateTime.Date);
    _apptDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(_apptCmd);
    _apptDa.Fill(_scheduleDataSet.appointments);
    _apptCb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_apptDa);
```

The _scheduleDataSet is a c# DataSet file and the appointments is a DataTable configured in it.  I think that this is what is taking care of the update, but I don't know why.

This is used to populate a table that the user can manipulte in the application.  Later on, after all of the changes are done, the changes are persisted to the database through the `DataAdapter.Update()` function.

```
    if (_scheduleDataSet.appointments.GetChanges() != null && _apptDa != null)
    {
        if (_apptCb == null)
        {
            _apptCb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_apptDa);
        }

        _apptDa.Update(_scheduleDataSet.appointments);
    }
```

When debugging, all of the commands are null and it shows that one change is a part of the UpdateBatchSize

[image: DataAdapter debugging]

This code works perfectly fine, but how does it know to update the appropriate table in the database when no `.Insert()` or `.Update()` functionality has been defined as part of the dataadapter?

**UPDATE**

As requested, I added a message box to show the number of updates.

[image: Update output image]

Comment: How do you know that there were any changes, I am pretty sure there weren't any.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I checked the database and verified the changes were persisted.

Comment: The command builder will generate insert and update commands on the fly for you.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Is there documentation for that anywhere?  I searched MSDN and didn't see anything that indicates that.

Comment: additional info : http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/c%23/id/4922

Comment: I just inspected the code of dbCommandBuilder. I'll update my answer with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code like this :

```
int nbrUpdates = _apptDa.Update(_scheduleDataSet.appointments);
MessageBox.Show(nbrUpdates.toString());
```

Just to verify that indeed updates are really happening. You did this and updates are in fact happening. Great!

The commandbuilder will anyway try to create the update and insert command based on the provided select command. But the question is when is it going to do that ?

When you instantiate the commandbuilder, it is going to set its dataadapter property. Like this :

```
public DbDataAdapter DataAdapter
{
  get
  {
    return this._dataAdapter;
  }
  set
  {
    if (this._dataAdapter == value)
      return;
    this.RefreshSchema();
    if (this._dataAdapter != null)
    {
      this.SetRowUpdatingHandler(this._dataAdapter);
      this._dataAdapter = (DbDataAdapter) null;
    }
    if (value == null)
      return;
    this.SetRowUpdatingHandler(value);
    this._dataAdapter = value;
  }
}
```

so it is hooking in some events. Anyway in the constructor you might expect that it would create an update delete and insert command but it is NOT doing that.
So what are the commands it is creating and when are they in fact created ?
Well, as I said there are some events registered, a rowupdateinghandler, the builder is for sure listening to some updating events and is going to react upon them. But it has some interested methods too :

for instance :

```
public SqlCommand GetInsertCommand()
{
  return (SqlCommand) base.GetInsertCommand();
}
```

and the eventhandler for rowupdateing is like this :

```
protected void RowUpdatingHandler(RowUpdatingEventArgs rowUpdatingEvent)
{
  if (rowUpdatingEvent == null)
    throw ADP.ArgumentNull("rowUpdatingEvent");
  try
  {
    if (rowUpdatingEvent.Status != UpdateStatus.Continue)
      return;
    StatementType statementType = rowUpdatingEvent.StatementType;
    DbCommand dbCommand1 = (DbCommand) rowUpdatingEvent.Command;
    if (dbCommand1 != null)
    {
      DbCommand dbCommand2;
      switch (statementType)
      {
        case StatementType.Select:
          return;
        case StatementType.Insert:
          dbCommand2 = this.InsertCommand;
          break;
        case StatementType.Update:
          dbCommand2 = this.UpdateCommand;
          break;
        case StatementType.Delete:
          dbCommand2 = this.DeleteCommand;
          break;
        default:
          throw ADP.InvalidStatementType(statementType);
      }
      if (dbCommand2 != rowUpdatingEvent.Command)
      {
        dbCommand1 = (DbCommand) rowUpdatingEvent.Command;
        if (dbCommand1 != null && dbCommand1.Connection == null)
        {
          DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = this.DataAdapter;
          DbCommand dbCommand3 = dataAdapter != null ? dataAdapter.SelectCommand : (DbCommand) null;
          if (dbCommand3 != null)
            dbCommand1.Connection = dbCommand3.Connection;
        }
      }
      else
        dbCommand1 = (DbCommand) null;
    }
    if (dbCommand1 != null)
      return;
    this.RowUpdatingHandlerBuilder(rowUpdatingEvent);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (!ADP.IsCatchableExceptionType(ex))
    {
      throw;
    }
    else
    {
      ADP.TraceExceptionForCapture(ex);
      rowUpdatingEvent.Status = UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred;
      rowUpdatingEvent.Errors = ex;
    }
  }
}
```

and you see that the updatecommand insertcommand and deletecommands get a value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually specify which table to update with the Update command.

```
daCountry.Update(dsCountry, "Country");
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html

This doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idataadapter.update.aspx
is dataadapter specs - states that it

> examines the RowState property, and executes the required INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements iteratively for each row

Basically, the whole thing is generated on the fly.

Comment: That would make sense, but the code isn't specifying the table to update as part of the fill command.

Comment: Well, imo, if you don't specify which table to update, it updates all tables from DS that it can match to DB tables whether by name or some other criteria.